# Python beaker session timeout minutes or seconds

Tags: python, bottle, beaker

Currently, I have set up my beaker session cookie_expires to 300.

```
'session.cookie_expires':300,
```

1.Is the 300 in minutes or seconds?
2. Will the created session will be automatically deleted after 300?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to the [documentation](https://beaker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html?highlight=timeout#session-options):

> timeout (optional, integer)
>
> **Seconds** until the session is considered invalid, **after which it will be ignored and invalidated**. This number is based on the time
>   since the session was last accessed, not from when the session was
>   created.
>
> Defaults to never expiring.